# WooCommerce shipping method duplication

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I just upgraded woocommerce from 2.3.10 to 3.2.6
I had legacy flat rate and free shipping methods before, and I created a new shipping zone and then added the shipping methods to this zone.
Of course, I disabled the legacy shipping methods, so it is not showing in the shipping tab.
On the front-end, everything looks working well.
My problem is on the back-end.
I have a custom cart on the backend, it uses WC()->shipping->load_shipping_methods($package) to get shipping methods and calculate shipping costs.
I need only one flat-rate but it is showing more than one.
I saw flat-rate, flat-rate:3 and flat-rate:5 through error log.
How can I get what I want? Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Can you add the complete code of your custom function editing your question please… thanks

Comment: I couldn't put the code here due to the limitation of characters.

Comment: So you should put outside in a code service website the related code and add a link in here, as nobody can really help you… actually your question is just unclear. Shipping in WooCommerce 3+ doesn't work anymore like in this very old WooCommerce version 2.3.x…

Comment: Thank you for your kindness. I could resolve myself by deleting some database records from wp_options table. WooCommerce probably didn't expect some people still use quite old versions like me.